# Read program STDIN in Delphi

Tags: delphi, stdin

I have the following batch script:

```
dir | myapp.exe
```

And the program has this source (more or less):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var buff: String;
begin
  Read(buff);
  Memo1.Lines.Text:=buff;
end;
```

And the output in the memo is:

> Volume in drive C has no label.

I tried:

- putting the read part into a loop with `eof` as a condition - somehow causing an infinite loop
- writing a loop to keep reading until `strlen(buff)` is 0 - it exits the second time for some reason
- reading stuff ever 0.5 seconds (I was thinking about asynchronous writes to stdin), this failed as well

By the way, running the program directly, without stdin data, causes an EInputOutput exception (I/O Error) code 6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GUI apps don't have a stdin, stdout or stderr assigned automatically. You can do something like:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buffer: array[0..1000] of Byte;
  StdIn: TStream;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  StdIn := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
  Count := StdIn.Read(Buffer, 1000);
  StdIn.Free;
  ShowMessageFmt('%d', [Count]);
end;
```

If you do

```
dir *.pas | myapp.exe
```

You'll see a messagebox with a number > 0, and if you do:

```
myapp.exe
```

You'll see a messagebox with 0. In both cases, the form will be shown.

Comment: OK, that works nicely! Do I keep reading until `Count<sizeOf(Buffer)`?

Comment: Yes, just keep on reading until Count < Sizeof(Buffer). Note that buffer is not necessarily zero-terminated, so use e.g. a TMemoryStream to add the buffer to and finally add a #0 at the end, so you can read it as a string.

Comment: FWIW, although I answer questions here, I am mostly here to learn. Especially Objective-C, but also C, C++ and stuff like algorithms, etc.

Answer (score 4):

try using a stream approach instead `Read(buff)`

```
InputStream := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
```